# Boost custom intervals with interval_map and closed bounds

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use `boost::icl::interval_map` with a custom interval `MyInterval` and closed bounds (`interval_bounds::static_closed`), similarly to `interval_set` [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/examples/custom_interval.html). This construct is, however, throwing the following error:

```
---- Map State -----------------
[0,10] - A

prog.exe: /opt/wandbox/boost-1.71.0/gcc-head/include/boost/icl/interval_base_map.hpp:557: boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::gap_insert(boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator, const interval_type&, const codomain_type&) [with Combiner = boost::icl::inplace_plus<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; SubType = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::icl::partial_absorber, std::less, boost::icl::inplace_plus, boost::icl::inter_section, MyInterval>; DomainT = int; CodomainT = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; Traits = boost::icl::partial_absorber; Compare = std::less; Combine = boost::icl::inplace_plus; Section = boost::icl::inter_section; Interval = MyInterval; Alloc = std::allocator; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree<MyInterval, std::pair<const MyInterval, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const MyInterval, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::icl::exclusive_less_than<MyInterval>, std::allocator<std::pair<const MyInterval, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >::iterator; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::interval_type = MyInterval; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::codomain_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]: Assertion `this->_map.find(inter_val) == this->_map.end()' failed.
```

I have noticed that either **(1)** using another `interval_bounds` type, e.g. `static_open`, or **(2)** using default `interval_type`, i.e.`interval<int>::closed()`, works just fine. Using `MyInterval` and `static_closed` bounds combination seems to be the problem. What configuration am I missing or what have I done incorrectly?

**Code:** below or [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HvphfqaMrwoNGIfB).

**Boost:** 1.71

**GCC:** 9.2.0.

### MyInterval.hxx

```
#ifndef MY_INTERVAL_HXX
#define MY_INTERVAL_HXX

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/icl/interval_map.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::icl;

class MyInterval
{
public:
  MyInterval(): _first(), _past(){}
  MyInterval(int lo, int up): _first(lo), _past(up){}
  int first()const{ return _first; }
  int past ()const{ return _past; }
private:
  int _first, _past;
};


namespace boost { namespace icl
{
  template<>
  struct interval_traits<MyInterval>
  {
    typedef MyInterval           interval_type;
    typedef int                  domain_type;
    typedef std::less<int>       domain_compare;

    static interval_type construct(const domain_type &lo, const domain_type &up)
    { return interval_type(lo, up); }

    static domain_type lower(const interval_type &inter_val) { return inter_val.first(); }
    static domain_type upper(const interval_type &inter_val) { return inter_val.past(); }
  };

  template<>
  struct interval_bound_type<MyInterval>
  {
    typedef interval_bound_type type;
    BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bound_type, value = interval_bounds::static_closed);
  };
}} // namespace boost icl

#endif
```

### Main.cxx

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <boost/icl/interval_map.hpp>
#include "MyInterval.hxx"

using namespace boost::icl;

int main()
{
    interval_map <int
      , std::string
      , partial_absorber
      , std::less // ICL_COMPARE_INSTANCE(ICL_COMPARE_DEFAULT, int),
      , inplace_plus // ICL_COMBINE_INSTANCE(inplace_plus, int),
      , inter_section // ICL_SECTION_INSTANCE(inter_section, int),
      , MyInterval
      > imap;

    std::string A("A");
    std::string B("B");
    std::string C("C");
    auto Ai = MyInterval(0,10);
    //auto Ai = interval<int>::closed(0,10);
    auto Bi = MyInterval(5,15);
    //auto Bi = interval<int>::closed(5,15);
    auto Ci = MyInterval(7,12);
    //auto Ci = interval<int>::closed(7,12);

    imap += std::make_pair(Ai, A);
    std::cout << "---- Map State -----------------" << std::endl;
    for (const auto& val : imap) { std::cout << val.first << " - " << val.second << std::endl; }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    imap += std::make_pair(Bi, B);
    std::cout << "---- Map State -----------------" << std::endl;
    for (const auto& val : imap) { std::cout << val.first << " - " << val.second << std::endl; }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    imap += std::make_pair(Ci, C);
    std::cout << "---- Map State -----------------" << std::endl;
    for (const auto& val : imap) { std::cout << val.first << " - " << val.second << std::endl; }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Expected Output

```
---- Map State -----------------
[0,10] - A

---- Map State -----------------
[0,5) - A
[5,10] - AB
(10,15] - B

---- Map State -----------------
[0,5) - A
[5,7) - AB
[7,10] - ABC
(10,12] - BC
(12,15] - B
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the same problem a friend of mine had once.

The problem is that the default constructor of your custom class is not right. I'm not sure if the *boost* documentation says this, but it must produce an invalid range. In your case, the default constructor is producing a range `[0, 0]`.

Basically, the way the library checks if a range is valid is based on the type of bounds:

- If it is `static_open`, for instance the function that checks if the interval is invalid is equivalent to `upper() <= lower()`. That is why it works in your code: `0 <= 0 -> true`.
- For the `static_closed`, the function that checks if the interval is invalid is equivalent to `upper() < lower()`.

In order for it to work, you need to change the default constructor to produce something where `upper() < lower()`.

#### TL;DR

Change the default constructor to something like:

```cpp
MyInterval() : _first(0), _past(-1) {}
```

Comment: This is some quality content. Thank you very much for sharing scarce experience!